# Separar paquetes en Modulos Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

Tengo los siguientes paquetes

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comunico cada paquete con Koin pero me gustaria poder generar

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cuales serian los pasos para pasar de un package a un module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para registrar un módulo realizalo en los siguientes 2 puntos:

Dentro de `settings.gradle` puedes definir los modulos. Por ejemplo suponiendo que se llama `BrunoModule`, lo agregas de esta forma:

```
include ':BrunoModule'
```

y dentro de tu archivo `app/build.gradle` en el bloque `dependencies` :

```
dependencies {
    ...
    ...
    implementation project(':BrunoModule')
}
```